# Do we call the tiny part running from the knot to the open-end of a balloon "the stem of the balloon"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

After blowing up a balloon, in order to prevent the air coming out you have to tie its open-end as shown in the picture.

Do we call the tiny part running from the knot to the open-end of the balloon "**the stem of the balloon**", e.g., "**hold the balloon by its stem**"?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Balloons are said to have necks:

Whether or not it has a knot in it.

> Neck The neck of a round balloon is the portion which connects its
> body to its inflation outlet. It is also the portion of a balloon
> which is tied into a knot to keep it inflated.

[Anatomy of a balloon](https://balloons.fandom.com/wiki/Anatomy_of_a_balloon)

[image]